# powershell - extract file name and extension

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to extract file name and extension from e.g. my.file.xlsx. I don't know the name of file or extension and there may be more dots in the name, so I need to search the string from the right and when I find first dot (or last from the left), extract the part on the right side and the part on the left side from that dot.

How?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

If the file is coming off the disk and as others have stated, use the `BaseName` and `Extension` properties:

```
PS C:\> dir *.xlsx | select BaseName,Extension

BaseName                                Extension
--------                                ---------
StackOverflow.com Test Config           .xlsx
```

If you are given the file name as part of string (say coming from a text file), I would use the `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `GetExtension` static methods from the [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class:

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("Test Config.xlsx")
Test Config
PS H:\> [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension("Test Config.xlsx")
.xlsx
```

Comment: For more useful methods in the System.IO.Path class without referring to MSDN documentation, you can use `[System.IO.Path] | Get-Member -Static`

Comment: Note that `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension` returns the extension *including the period (".")*.

Answer (score 33):

just do it:

```
$file=Get-Item "C:\temp\file.htm"
$file.Basename 
$file.Extension
```

Comment: I think it should be `$file.Basename`

Comment: This is the ideal answer if the file exists, otherwise you'll get an `ObjectNotFound` exception.

Answer (score 23):

`split-path` has a `-leaf` flag, which will extract the file name and extension from a given path.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>split-path "H:\Documents\devops\tp-mkt-SPD-38.4.10.msi" -leaf
tp-mkt-SPD-38.4.10.msi

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5477
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: This is obviously not an answer

Answer (score 16):

Use Split-Path

```
$filePath = "C:\PS\Test.Documents\myTestFile.txt";
$fileName = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[0];
$extension = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[1];
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if there is no periods in the filename.

Comment: you can change to `Split(".")[-1]` to make it work with files with dots in the name

Comment: @phuclv This solution returns the extension for files with typical `name.extension` format.

Comment: So would Split(".")[-1].

Answer (score 14):

If is from a text file and and presuming name file are surrounded by white spaces this is a way:

```
$a = get-content c:\myfile.txt

$b = $a | select-string -pattern "\s.+\..{3,4}\s" | select -ExpandProperty matches | select -ExpandProperty value

$b | % {"File name:{0} - Extension:{1}" -f $_.substring(0, $_.lastindexof('.')) , $_.substring($_.lastindexof('.'), ($_.length - $_.lastindexof('.'))) }
```

If is a file you can use something like this based on your needs:

```
$a = dir .\my.file.xlsx # or $a = get-item c:\my.file.xlsx 

$a
    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\ps


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
-a---      25/01/10    11.51          624 my.file.xlsx


$a.BaseName
my.file
$a.Extension
.xlsx
```

Answer (score 11):

```
PS C:\Users\joshua> $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo('file.type')
PS C:\Users\joshua> $file.BaseName, $file.Extension
file
.type
```

Answer (score 8):

Check the BaseName and Extension properties of the FileInfo object.

Comment: Any particular infoyou're after? Just pipe a file to Get-Member to reveal all of it;s members or browse to MSDN to find the official help.

Answer (score 2):

As of PowerShell 6.0, [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7) has an [`-Extenstion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter. This means you can do:

```
$path | Split-Path -Extension
```

or

```
Split-Path -Path $path -Extension
```

For `$path = "test.txt"` both versions will return `.txt`, inluding the full stop.

Answer (score 1):

if `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` is hard to type or remember:

```
("file.name.ext.w..dots.ext" -split '\.' | select -SkipLast 1) -join '.'
# >> file.name.ext.w..dots

"file.name.ext.w..dots.ext" -split '\.' | select -Last 1
# >> ext
```

Notes:

`-split` takes a regex (by default) so the `.` has to be escaped

I don't think there's a "locale" name.ext filename separator, is there?

`-SkipLast` was added in v5.0

The .NET function `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension()` returns the extension *including* the '.' char; the above returns it *without*

having to -rejoin the string after splitting could change the result, I suppose, in unusual circumstances. Or if you're uncomfortable re-joining a string that's already joined, one could:

```
$file = "file.name.ext.w..dots.ext"
$ext = $file -split '\.' | select -Last 1
$name = $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf(".$ext"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation, if anyone is curious. I needed to test whether RoboCopy successfully copied one file to multiple servers for its integrity:

```
   $Comp = get-content c:\myfile.txt

ForEach ($PC in $Comp) {
    dir "\\$PC\Folder\Share\*.*" | Select-Object $_.BaseName
}
```

Nice and simple, and it shows the directory and the file inside it. If you want to specify one file name or extension, just replace the *'s with whatever you want.

```
    Directory: \\SERVER\Folder\Share

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                             
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                             
-a---         2/27/2015   5:33 PM    1458935 Test.pptx
```